# Make MYSQL on Linux able to be accessed remotely

Tags: mysql, linux, database, server, remote-access

I have my database built in MYSQl on Linux.

I want to be able to connect to the server remotely.

Answer (score 4):

General steps for connecting to MySQL remotely:

1.- Create an account for the remote user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'remoteuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret-passwd'
```

2.- Open port 3306, this will very depending on your linux distribution, eg: in CentOS 6.5 will be:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

3.- Connect remotely, in this example I will use the *mysqli* client

```
mysql -h remote.mysqlserver.com -u remoteuser -p
```

Good luck!

Comment: not best practices, `*.*` let's clean that one up. How about the `my.cnf`?

Comment: Allowing all ips to be connected '%'  is not a best practice

Comment: Ok.

I am building Java project that lets me connecto to the database.

it should work now?

Comment: @MarcusDeclementi Yes. It would be nice if you accept it as the answer.